# Turn off target when using submenu on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar where the 4 links take you to a location on the page and the submenu is hidden in desktop view. Can I turn that 'target #' off when in mobile view so clicking on the nav links will open a submenu instead of jumping to a location on the page?

Example of one of a nav link with a submenu:

```
<li>
   <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="page-scroll dropdown">
   <a href="#about" class="page-scroll dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who are we <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Case studies</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">The Company</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
   </ul> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below css property to disable link in our media query

```
.dropdown-menu a{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see how that works, but it seems to deactivate the link so the dropdown menu doesn't work.